# Find $k$ such that the vector with $w_n=1/(1+a_n k)$ is orthogonal to a given vector

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am a little rusted. I have a vector $v$ with components $v_n$ in $R^N$, and another vector $w$ with  components $w_n=\dfrac{1}{1+a_n k}$ in $R^N$. I have to find the value $k$ for which $v\cdot w=0$. Wich is the analytical solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $\vec{v} = (v_k)_{k=1}^N$ and $\vec{w} = \left( \frac{1}{1+a_n k} \right)_{n=1}^N$. You must find
$$
0 = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{w} = \sum_{i=1}^N v_i w_i = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{v_i}{1+a_i k}.
$$
Can you continue from here? (Using numerical techniques, like Bisection or Newton's Methods, looks much easier unless $N$ is very small...)

Comment: Sorry? This is simply what I have stated in the question. Anyway I am looking for an analytical solution for k.

Comment: @emanuele Lots of people ask questions here without any clue as to what the definitions mean. I am glad you understand. So for each $N$ you must find roots of a polynomial of degree $N$ to get the values. E.g. no guarantees for $N=1$, and
$$
-\frac{v_1+v_2}{v_1 a_2 - v_2 a_1}
$$
for $N=2$. So you can possibly find more analytical solution for $N=3,4$ but no more than that.

Comment: So the answer is, "Sorry no analytical solution" ?

Comment: @emanuele Not a general one, unfortunately. There are ones for $N=2,3,4$. Why not be happy with a numerical one?

Comment: Actually, I have no trouble with numerical solution, but I would had bet on the existence of an analytic one. Anyway thanx for the answer.